# Switch for text-only mode

Tags: feature-request

Right now some buttons are invisible because they use images which fail to load.

It would be awesome to be able to use StackOverflow in text only mode. Have you considered that?

It could be specified by a URL parameter such as `stackoverflow.com/textonly/question/ask`.

Comment: http://stackapps.com/questions/542/column-80-plain-text-optimised-sofu

Comment: Any reason *why*?

Comment: @Arjan For the blind of course. They can't see images.......wait...

Comment: It seems visually impaired (even totally blind) people [can use Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/118984/how-can-you-program-if-youre-blind/148880#148880) without such text mode. Of course, maybe things can be improved, but a random *"it would be awesome"* request doesn't sound like [time well spent](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/?tab=requests), @Bart?

Comment: Just use a text only browser like lynx.

Comment: @Arjan just kidding. But yeah, some reasoning would be nice.

Comment: @orian Could you please clarify which buttons are failing to load? Is it the voting and favorite buttons? These are loaded from a different domain, so it is possible for them to fail to load or be blocked when the main site loads fine. It doesn't happen often but it has happened to me occasionally. Perhaps this case could be handled more nicely.

Comment: @JeremyBanksᐛ: You are changing OP's question. His problem was that the pictures "failed to load". You removed that.

Comment: @false Actually, I edited that into his post. (See revision 2.) I removed it because I realized that his original post didn't actually say that, and I was putting words in his mouth.

Answer (score -1):

Click on the **| mobile |** link at the bottom of each page.

[image: Mobile link]

Comment: That probably won't fix the OP's problem. He's having an issue with buttons being invisible because the image won't load, and the mobile site still uses images for the same buttons. (Up/downvote, favorite.)

Comment: OP did not say which browser, and why at all this is necessary. And OP did not consider mobile at all.